# How to hide sub fields in a field group and also the entire field group if the answer selected is "no"

Tags: custom-post-types, query, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field group (repeater field type) set up (titled "Units") with sub fields; sq footage, floor plans and availability (this is a yes/no selection). I have the availability sub field to display on the front end as "Yes" or "No" but I don't want the Units to show up on the front end that have the "No" availability selected. I am not sure what to do to get the "No" units to hide when that is selected as well as the whole field group to hide if there are no "Yes" units in the group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you can add

```
$available = get_sub_field('available');
if($available == 'yes'){
   //your row rendering code
}
```

Switch 'available' with whatever you named that field.